# There is a GUI to manage OSGi services? (in Eclipse or another project)

Tags: user-interface, osgi, equinox

I'm working with an application that uses and manages a large amount of OSGi services and implementations for each service, with properties, dynamism and so. Using the command line of the Equinox console is useful, with commands like *services* or *list -c* . However, it is difficult to see specific implementations of services, and obtain a current snapshot of bounded or available services to consume. For example, you can see if the bundle references are satisfied, but you can't see which are the implementations of those satisfied references (although there are another mechanisms, of course).

So, the idea is to find a GUI with organized information (for example, using graphs) to increase the performance when you are developing in OSGi. Maybe there is one GUI in Eclipse plug-in perspective, but I can't find it.

If you don't know anything like this, I've in mind to create my own for my thesis :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse has its *Plug-in Registry* view:

**Window > Show View > Other... > Plug-in Development -> Plug-in Registry**

This view comes with the *Plug-in Development Environment* (PDE), so you'll need to either use *Eclipse Classic* or *Eclipse for Plug-in Developers* or install it additionally through the standard Eclipse update mechanism.

The view can show the plugins, running in the current Eclipse instance and group them by plugin, extension points or services. I believe the last option is what you are searching for.

Although there was some work to make this view show remote content as well, it appears that this functionality hasn't made it to the normal Eclipse release.

Another tool, which can assist you in OSGi development is [mToolkit](http://mtoolkit.tigris.org). It is open source project, specifically aimed at helping developing in OSGi environments.

It provides similar view to the *Plug-in Registry*, but it only shows information about the OSGi bundles and services. It doesn't support nothing outside OSGi specification, so no plug-in registry inspection.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. However, I still think that a graph could be a better way to see the service injection and all that stuff. Maybe in future.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Felix console provides a web interface to manage OSGi services (and many other things) - I haven't tested it with Equinox but it has minimal dependencies so it should work in most OSGi environments. See http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout Peter Krien's Xray http://softwaresimplexity.blogspot.com/2012/07/xray-again.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Knopflerfish](http://www.knopflerfish.org/) and [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) UIs? I think, they could be installed on top of Equinox as well.